# How can I replace the MonthHeader component within the StatefulCalendar with a custom component that displays just the month name in Base Web?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, baseweb

I am trying to replace the `MonthHeader` component within a Base Web `StatefulCalendar` component using overrides but unfortunately I can only get it to return the `{monthName}` containing an appended year.

I have reproduced the issue in a [sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/determined-morning-wtlyfx).

There is also a screenshot below.

How can I remove the year from the output?

[image]